# Portable JPA 2.0 select current date/time/timestamp

Tags: postgresql, jpa, oracle11g, jpa-2.0, oracle12c

Is it possible to make portable JPA 2.0 query that select current date/time/timestamp using JPA reserved keywords CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

I know this works in Oracle 11g:

```
<named-native-query name="getOracleSysdate">
     <query>SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL</query>
</named-native-query>
```

And i know this works in PostgreSQL:

```
<named-native-query name="getPostgreCurrentTimestamp">
    <query>SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</query>
</named-native-query>
```

My question is basicly, will this 2nd query (for PostgreSQL) work on every database?
If not, then is it possible to write **named-query** (not **named-native-query**) for application to be portable? At least portable between PostgreSQL and Oracle 11g/12c? Or CriteriaApi query?

Comment: Those two query are returning different things. The first returns a string (`varchar`), the second returns a `timestamp`.

Comment: i know, i didn't say they're same, i just said they're both working :)

Comment: i just want portable current date and time from database, in any form

Answer (score 0):

OK the best i could think of is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm_db_oracle.xml</mapping-file>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And 2 ORM files depending on database type, first one is for Oracle 11g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">

    <named-native-query name="getCurrentDateAndTimeFromDatabase">
        <query>SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL</query>
    </named-native-query>

</entity-mappings>
```

And the one for PostgreSQL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">

    <named-native-query name="getCurrentDateAndTimeFromDatabase">
        <query>SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</query>
    </named-native-query>

</entity-mappings>
```

I can then switch them with Maven profiles.

Notice Oracle CURRENT_DATE is equivalent (or most similar) to PostgreSQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. If i ask Oracle to return CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, JPA will try to cast to Java object with timezones included, and if i ask PostgreSQL to return CURRENT_DATE, i don't get TIME portion in java.util.Date.